# Selecting specific elements from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I’m trying to solve a tricky problem here. Whenever there are 3 rows together (e.g. 3A, 3B & 3C), I want to increment the variable ‘count’. My logic only works for the first row but then fails for the rest. The answer to this problem should be 3. Can someone shed some light here?

```
function doThis() {
    var everySeat = [1A, 1B, 1C, 2A, 2C, 3A, 3B, 3C, 151A, 151B, 151C, 152B, 152C];
    var count;

    for (i = 1; i <= everySeat.length; i++) {
        if (everySeat[i-1] = i + ‘A’ && everySeat[i] = i + ‘B’ && everySeat[i+1] = i + ‘C’) {
            count++;
        }
    }

}

doThis();
```

Comment: you should use comparison operator `==` in `if` condition

Comment: And an array that isn't a syntax error ?

Comment: I would use two dimensions array for seat[A,B,C][Number]
example: everySeat[A][1,2,3,4,...] everySeat[B][1,2,3,4,...]
Less mess ;)

Comment: You have items in your array, the `151 and 152` values that will never match the condition of your loop

Comment: Logging your values as you go along would help you understand what is going on. Your first condition matches because your loop value matches 1. When you get to your later values like `3` that your are trying to match, your `i` is now `6` so youre comparing 3A (`everySeat[i-1]`) to 6A (`i+"A"`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Works fine.

```
function doThis() {
    var everySeat = ['1A', '1B', '1C', '2A', '2C', '3A', '3B', '3C', '151A', '151B', '151C', '152B', '152C'];
    var count = 0;

    for (var i = 1; i <= everySeat.length-2; i++) {
        var prefix = parseInt(everySeat[i-1]);
        if (everySeat[i-1] == prefix + 'A' && everySeat[i] == prefix + 'B' && everySeat[i+1] == prefix + 'C') {
            count++;
        }
    }
return count;
}
```

Comment: on second thought, would it not be for (var i = 1; i <= everySeat.length-1; i++) { as just everySeat.length? otherwise it would be 1 iteration out

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you array has syntax error. SO try below code.

```
var everySeat = ['1A', '1B', '1C', '2A', '2C', '3A', '3B', '3C', '151A', '151B', '151C', '152B', '152C'];
    var count =0;
    for(var i =0; i < everySeat.length ; i++ ){
    if(everySeat[i] == i + 'A' && everySeat[i+1] == i + 'B' && everySeat[i+2] == i + 'C'  ){
    count++;
    }
    }
    console.log(count);
```

Comment: I would also add that the for loop should go till everySeat.length-2, as it stands, you'll be trying to access non-existing elements

Answer (score 0):

Extended solution with `Array.slice()` and `String.match()` functions:

```js
var everySeat = ['1A', '1B', '1C', '2A', '2C', '3A', '3B', '3C', '151A', '151B', '151C', '152B', '152C'],
    count = 0;
 
for (var i=0, l=everySeat.length; i < l-2; i++) {
    if (String(everySeat.slice(i,i+3)).match(/\d+A,\d+B,\d+C/)) {
        count++;
        i +=2;
    } 
}

console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it in string then match required substring occurrence.

```
var everySeat = ['1A', '1B', '1C', '2A', '2C', '3A', '3B', '3C', '151A', '151B', '151C', '152B', '152C'];
var str = everySeat.toString();
var count1 = (str.match(/3A,3B,3C/g) || []).length;
console.log(count1);
```

Comment: Thats only works if he knows he is looking to match 3A, B, and C and does not solve the question. The answer should be 3

Answer (score 0):

You could take a hash table for counting rows and add one if count is three for a row.

This proposal works for unsorted data as well.

```js
var array = ['1A', '1B', '1C', '2A', '2C', '3A', '3B', '3C', '151A', '151B', '151C', '152B', '152C'],
    count = Object.create(null),
    result = array.reduce(function (r, s) {
        var key = s.match(/\d+/)[0];
        count[key] = (count[key] || 0) + 1;
        return r + (count[key] === 3);
    }, 0);

console.log(result);
```